# rlang::enexprs() works inconsistently

Tags: r, rlang

I'm learning more about programming with R but I'm puzzled as to the behavior below. Essentially minor changes/variations in the code can produce different results.
Any thoughts on why no named argument example below doesn't return the consistent results?

1. no named arguments -- only lists last formula
2. named arguments --works as expected
3. including the data.frame in the function (unnamed arguments) -- work as expected

### No named arguments (only returns last formula

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rlang)

test <- function(.data, ...) {
  cols <- rlang::enexprs(...)
  mtcars %>% 
    reframe(
      !!!cols
    )
}

test(
  median(mpg),
  mean(vs)
)
```

### named arguments

```
test <- function(.data,...){
  
  cols <-  rlang::enexprs(...)
  mtcars %>% 
    reframe(
      !!!cols
    )
    
  
  
}

test(
  median=median(mpg)
  ,mean=mean(vs)
 
  )
```

#### include data.frame unnamed argument

```
test <- function(.data, ...) {
  cols <- rlang::enexprs(...)
  .data %>% 
    reframe(
      !!!cols
    )
}

test(
  mtcars,
  median(mpg),
  mean(vs)
)
```

Comment: With 'no named args' the function is assigning median(mpg) to ".data" (doesn't get used). If you edit your function from `test <- function(.data, ...) {` to `test <- function(...) {` it should work as expected. Does that answer your question? Or have I misunderstood?

Comment: thank you!! I must have missed that. sometimes staring at your code for too long works against you.

Comment: Glad you solved your problem :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Jaret Mamrot already suggests in the comments, the problem is in your `.data` arg. Either drop it as suggested by Jaret or use it. In either case named arguments are working fine:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(rlang)

test <- function(.dat, ...) {
  cols <- rlang::enexprs(...)
  .dat %>% # <- here we actually use the .data arg
    reframe(
      !!! cols
    )
}

test(mtcars,
  median(mpg),
  mean(vs)
)
#>   median(mpg) mean(vs)
#> 1        19.2   0.4375

test(mtcars,
  median = median(mpg),
  mean   = mean(vs)
)
#>   median   mean
#> 1   19.2 0.4375
```

<sup>Created on 2023-07-25 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>